# Checking CSS title attribute if it's not empty and add content

Tags: css, css-selectors

My goal is to: check if the title attribute is not empty; if it is not then there should be added the value of this title attribute plus a hyphen. On the other hand, if the title attribute is empty then the " - " should not be added at all.

Here is my current CSS code:

```
div:hover::before{content:attr(title):not(attr(title)="") " - ";}
```

but it doesn’t work as expected.

For example:

```
<div title="My username">some text</div>
```

should display the following on hover:

> My username - some text

But if:

```
<div title="">some text</div>
```

or (no title on div):

```
<div>some text</div>
```

then the display on hover should be:

> some text

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors in conjunction with the `attr()` function to accomplish this. The `attr()` function simply grabs the value of a given attribute — it does not support any conditional statements itself.

Notice that I use `[title=""]` and `:not([title])` to account for both empty title attributes as well as the lack of a title attribute altogether. You could omit the `:not()` part by including `[title]` in your first rule instead, but that doesn't work in Internet E— sorry, I meant it doesn't work in **Chrome**.

```css
div:hover::before {
    content: attr(title) " - ";
}

div[title=""]:hover::before, div:not([title]):hover::before {
    content: none;
}
```

```html
<div title="My username">some text</div>
<div title="">some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
```

Comment: This is a very cool use of CSS, but I think javaScript is a more appropriate solution; because this is beyond the scope of styling & I think its best to keep them separate.

Comment: @deraad: I don't see how this is beyond the scope of styling. `:hover` has existed since the dawn of CSS, attribute selectors nearly as long, and generated content was designed specifically for situations like this, among others. There is no reason authors should have to avoid using them together. Maybe if the `title` attribute were changed to `data-username` or something more appropriate for the markup...

Comment: True, you are correct in that you can use it this way. My comment relates more to keeping things in the right places, for instance when a project grows and you have many events such as clicks, hovers, mouseout, etc that you cannot satisfy with CSS alone. it may become disorganized and confusing to identify if the event behavior is written in javascript or CSS, especially if working in a team. Its something I've run into in the past, so just my opinion really, obviously it is indeed still valid nonetheless.

Comment: What if the div doesn't contain the title attribute at all, like:

<div>some text</div>

Would it still work?

Comment: @NonCoder: Yes, I specifically account for this case in my answer.