# Why doesn't css dataattribute selection hover respond in chrome within a handlebars template

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, handlebars.js

I'm wanting to highlight the text in a particular column of a table red on hover.

I'm selecting the cells with data attribute 'data-highlight' like this:

```
[data-highlight]:hover {
  color:red;
  }
```

This works fine until you try to do it within a handlebarsjs datatemplate.

Works in IE but not in chrome.

I have an example in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q4u0zrn2/1/

When you hover over the items in the Job Title column in IE they turn red. This doesn't happen in chrome.

Can anyone explain why and suggest a fix?

Comment: Huh... From a first glance looks like it should be picked up.

Comment: looks like it but if you try it's not

Comment: I thought they fixed this ages ago. Guess not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in chrome, using the `:hover` selector in combination with `td[attr]` selector doesn't work.

Here's minimal example that reproduces the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/q4u0zrn2/12/

The example also has some workarounds: wrap your content in a `div` with the proper attribute or use a different selector, e.g. a class selector.

Comment: Attribute selectors in general are quite broken in Chrome - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372281/checking-css-title-attribute-if-its-not-empty-and-add-content/27372509#27372509 (where I first discovered this bug) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951822/combine-css-attribute-and-pseudo-element-selectors/8988418#8988418

Comment: In case someone gets here note that *Chrome have fixed this bug*. I use Chrome 59, everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is a bug in chrome.

you can work around it by adding this css before:

```
[data-highlight] {
    cursor:default;
}
```

see your fixed sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/q4u0zrn2/14/